# HTML5 Video Autoplay on iOS

Tags: ios, html, html5-video

So I have a video that I need to autoplay. It works pretty well on Android(Chrome & FF) but iOS Safari does not seem to want to autoplay the video. Here is the code I am using (its a twig template) -

```
<video class="home-video"  poster="{{paths.files}}{{record.templatefields.video_poster}}" 
autoplay loop muted controls >
  <source src="{{paths.files}}{{record.templatefields.video}}" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="{{paths.files}}{{record.templatefields.video_ogg}}" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

I have already read https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios
I have ensure the video does not have any audio track so it should not be a problem. The device is using iOS 10+

Any clues would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Add the 'playsinline' attribute. Also ensure no other elements are on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Add playsinline attribute.

If your video is out of viewport or behind other elements, use javascript play() shortly after pageload, this may help (as long as other needed attributes are set).

Using jQuery (extracted from my bigger jQuery plugin):

```
var start_video = function($target){

    var video_width = $target.width();
    var video_height = $target.height();

    // if not loaded yet, wait another 500ms
    if ($target.get(0).readyState < 2 || video_width == 0 || video_height == 0){
        setTimeout(function(){
            start_video($target);
        }, 500);
        return;
    }

    $target.get(0).play();

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    start_video($('.home-video'));
}
```